# Django Form Not Re-Rendering On Page Refresh

Tags: python, django

I'm building a URL shortener in Django. I have a Django form to submit URLs, which has a default field with a random extension. When I finish submitting a URL to shorten, i'm returning a new form to the template, so that way you can submit a new URL.

```
return render(request, 'bitly/index.html', {
       "form": NewBitForm()
})
```

But when it renders, it leaves the old extension instead of rendering a new one, even after refreshing the page. How can I make it so that when I call `NewBitForm()`, it returns a different extension in the form?

Template:

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{% url 'bitly:index' %}" method="post">
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control">
            {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Form Class:

```
ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
class NewBitForm(forms.Form):
    def get_string(k):
        global ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARS
        return ''.join(random.choice(ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARS) for i in range(k))

    url = forms.CharField(label="URL to shorten")
    url.widget.attrs.update({
        'class': 'card mb-3 form-control',
        'spellcheck': 'false'
    })

    extension = forms.CharField(label="Effective Extension")
    extension.widget.attrs.update({
        'id': 'extension-field',
        'class': 'card mb-3 form-control',
        'spellcheck': 'false',
        'value': get_string(5)
    })
```